# Android: Action bar for phones

Tags: android, attributes, styles, android-actionbar

I was trying to extract the action bar from the [Google I/O 2011 app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/#hg%2Fandroid), but I cannot seem to figure out how they set the title and buttons on the bar. Basically I couldn't figure out how the `<declare-stylable>` worked.

So in the `attr.xml`, they have declared this

```
  <declare-styleable name="AppTheme">
    <attr name="actionbarButtonStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="actionbarProgressIndicatorStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="actionbarSeparatorStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="actionbarLogoStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="actionbarTextStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="textHeaderMaxLines" format="integer" />
    <attr name="trackAbstractMaxLines" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

In `styles.xml`,

```
 <style name="ActionBarLogo">
    <item name="android:id">@id/actionbar_logo</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">false</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">Logo</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
</style>
```

And I guess I should be using this code to add the logo to the bar,

```
ImageButton logo = new ImageButton(mActivity, null, R.attr.actionbarLogoStyle);
logo.setOnClickListener(homeClickListener);
actionBarCompat.addView(logo);
```

But nothing happens. I know I have missed out something while copy/pasting :D but I cannot figure out what!..

Also what is the use of `declare-stylable` an what does the `format=reference` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might want to use [something that is already a reusable component](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar).

> what is the use of declare-stylable

That is used by custom Views to declare custom attributes that you can supply in your layouts.

> what does the format=reference do

That indicates that the custom attribute takes, as a value, a reference to a resource. In this case, it would appear to be references to style resources.

Comment: Thankyou, that worked flawlessly. But could you also please explain how Google has done it? Just curious. I found that their action bar layout din't have the whole layout predefined.

Comment: Hi, did You figured out hot they do it ? I have the same issue. I tried it with TextView and it isn't styled too.